# How to create a 9 patch image for a spinner in android?

Tags: android

```
<Spinner 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner"
    android:entries="@array/Nithin"/>
```

The above is my spinner.xml code but my background image is not 9 patch image, so while using the `wrap_content` the image shows with a blur.

Comment: can you show your spinner background image

Answer (score 0):

To create 9patch image in android you should use draw9patch tool, that is available in your SDK Directory/tools. for reference go through [This](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html), hope this will help you.